# Correcting a quiz

Tags: coffeescript, quiz

I wrote this code that's supposed to correct quizzes on a webpage, but it feels bloated and I'm sure there's tons of ways to improve it. Any thoughts?

```
$ ->
  #When submit_quiz div is clicked, do the following
  $(document).on "click", "#submit_quiz", (e) ->
    #Gets the quiz id for later use
    qid = getQuestions(this)

    #console.log qid
    #Create a jquery object for the specific quiz div, select the quiz
    quiz = $("#quiz_"+qid)

    #Setup some variables to be used later
    window.qn = null
    window.checked = null
    wrong = []

    #Select questions inside the quiz
    quizchild = quiz.children() #Gets all questions like so in an object, I THINK

    #Loop through the questions one at a time
    for z,y in quizchild
      #Iterate if id = submit_quiz
      if $(z).attr('id') == 'submit_quiz'
        break

      #Get children of a question
      question = $(z).children()

      #Loop through the options
      for u,i in question

        #Check if the id exists, so it ignores <br>
        if $(u).attr('id')?

          #Set the length of our option array
          window.qn = $(u).length
          #The correct answer to the question, modify later
          correct = null

          #Get children of options, used for getting each individual options params
          options = $(question).children()

          #Loop the options and check if they're correct, if it's wrong, push it to a variable 'wrong' for later use
          for d,i in options
            child = $(d).children()[1]
            if $(child).is(":checked")
              window.checked+=1
              if $(child).attr('id') == 'correct'
                correct = $(child).attr('id')
              else
                $(child).css("color", "red")
                wrong.push $(u).attr('id')

      #Check if 'wrong' has anything in it
      if wrong.present()
        for o,i in wrong
          $('#'+o).css('color', 'red')

          console.log o
          console.log "This quiz is wrong.. This is bad!"

        #If it hasn't, check if all boxes are filled, if they are, the quiz is correctly answered
      else if !wrong.present() && window.checked == window.qn + 1
        console.log "This quiz is correctly answered yes guys!!!!"
        #Else, not all boxes are checked
      else
        console.log "Not all boxes in this quiz checked!"

Array::present = ->
  @.length > 0

getQuestions = (thiss) ->
  fvalue = $(thiss).attr("quiz")
  return fvalue
```

Bear with me on the obsolete comments and console logs please.

Comment: Looks to me like your HTML could use a going-over too. Can you post it?